# How to scan near by bluetooth devices in background mode or screen lock mode

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth

I am using core Bluetooth central manager and peripheral functionality for one of my applications. In which I want to find nearby devices based on Bluetooth name.

Can anyone share a reference link or sample code to scan nearby Bluetooth devices in background mode or screen lock mode

Comment: You can't scan by name. You have to look for a specific service identifier.  There's nothing special to do. Enable the Bluetooth background capability and set up the scan for the relevant service. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW1

Comment: Can I use an iOS device to iBeacon advertisements while my app is in the 
background?

Comment: Your device cannot act as an iBeacon when your app is in the background.  Your device can scan for iBeacon regions (Using Core Location) if you have always/background location permission